# How to normalize and regroup scraped gov earthquake data with pandas by criteria

Tags: python, json, pandas, urllib

Please help me implement a function that will group the earthquake data by the following criteria:

- Light (4.5-4.9)
- Moderate(5-5.9)
- Major (6-6.9)
- Strong (>=7)

I'm trying to add this to my simple program that collects data about earthquakes from a webpage.

```
import json
import urllib.request
handle = urllib.request.urlopen("https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/4.5_month.geojson")
rawdata = handle.read()
rawdata[:400]

data = json.loads(rawdata)
data

def get_earthquake_magnitude(json_data):
    results = []
    for eq in json_data['features']:
        mag = eq['properties']['mag']
        results.append(mag)
    return results

get_earthquake_magnitude(data)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Using a library like Pandas might be the better way to do this.  But if you want to do this just with basic Python code, here's a way:

```
import json
import urllib.request
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

handle = urllib.request.urlopen("https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/4.5_month.geojson")
rawdata = handle.read()

data = json.loads(rawdata)

ranges = [
    ("Light", 5),
    ("Moderate", 6),
    ("Major", 7)]

def get_earthquake_magnitude(json_data):
    groups = defaultdict(list)
    for eq in json_data['features']:
        mag = eq['properties']['mag']
        for range in ranges:
            if mag < range[1]:
                groups[range[0]].append(eq)
                break
        else:
            groups["Strong"] = eq
    return groups

r = get_earthquake_magnitude(data)

for label, group in r.items():
    print(f"{label}: {len(group)}")
```

Result:

```
Light: 525
Moderate: 115
Major: 8
```

This will give you a dictionary where the keys are each of the four labels for magnitude, and the values are lists of the complete data record for each earthquake in that category.

Comment: It's unclear to me how you end up with `Strong: 4`, there aren't any entries with `mag >= 7`. The max is `6.7`.

Comment: Oops.  You're right.  My "else" block was indented one level too much.  I'll fix that.  Helps to know the data, eh?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the implementation above, I am just adding a minimal example. Hope it could be of some help.

```
from collections import defaultdict

# Light (4.5-4.9)
# Moderate(5-5.9)
# Major (6-6.9)
# Strong (>=7)

# vals denoting the earthquake data
vals = [4.79, 4.58, 5.8]
mydt = {
"Light": lambda x: (x > 4.5) and (x < 4.9),
"Moderate": lambda x: (x > 5) and (x < 5.9)
       }
 dt = defaultdict(list)
 for val in vals:
   for k, v in mydt.items():
     if v(val):
       dt[k].append(val)
 print(f"dt = {dt}")
 
 # Output:
 dt = defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Light': [4.79, 4.58], 'Moderate': [5.8]})
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html#user-guide) library is great for something like this. Try as follows:

- Use [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) to create a `DataFrame`.
- Use [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) to bin the values from column `properties.mag` into discrete intervals.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.json_normalize(data['features'])

bins = [0, 5, 6, 7, 100]
labels = ['Light','Moderate','Major','Strong']

df['bins'] = pd.cut(df['properties.mag'], bins=bins, 
                    labels=labels, right=False)
```

Let's check how many entries we have for the bins, using [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and applying `count` to column `properties.mag`:

```
counts = df.groupby('bins')['properties.mag'].count()

print(counts)
bins
Light       531
Moderate    118
Major         8
Strong        0
Name: properties.mag, dtype: int64
```

Use [`df.describe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html) and [`df.info`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.info.html) to get a statistical summary and some basic info on your `df` respectively.